# How to search thoroughly in a list-dictionary to get the right results

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is my code:

```
dicto = [{100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3, 70: 4}, {100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3}, {105: 1, 100: 2, 90: 3, 80: 4}]
listo = [70,80,105]
track = []
for y in dicto:
    for x in listo:
        try:
           track.append(y[x])
        except KeyError:
           pass
print(track)
```

What I am trying to do is to use the numbers in 'listo' as keys to get the proper values. The first number in listo can only be searched on the first dictionary in 'dicto'. The second number in listo can only be searched in the second dictionary in the dicto, but not the first dictionary or the third one. The third number in listo can also only be searched in the third dictionary in dicto, not the other ones.

The output should be like this:

```
[4,3,1]
```

But my code is returning:

```
[4,3,3,4,1]
```

How can I fix my code to give the correct output in Python 3.x

Comment: lol. dicto and listo. Now I know what to name my kids!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip`.

```
dicto = [{100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3, 70: 4}, {100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3}, {105: 1, 100: 2, 90: 3, 80: 4}]
listo = [70,80,105]

track = []
for key, d in zip(listo, dicto):
    try:
        track.append(d[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

print(track)
# [4, 3, 1]
```

If you want `None` as the value if the key is missing, you can use this:

```
track = [d.get(key) for key, d in zip(listo, dicto)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
track = [dicto[index].get(value,None) for index,value in enumerate(listo)]
track = [item for item in track if item is not None]
print(track)
# [4, 3, 1]
```

This just checks for key-value at a particular index only. 
Without list comprehension,

```
track = []
for index,value in enumerate(listo):
    val = dicto[index].get(value,None)
    if val is not None:
        track.append(val)
print(track)
```

Comment: can do it in a single line using `track = [dicto[index].get(value,None) for index,value in enumerate(listo) if value in dicto[index]]` :p

Comment: Yes, I can also use a simple for loop instead of doing list comprehension twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
In [4]: [j.get(i) for i,j in zip(listo,dicto)]
Out[4]: [4, 3, 1]
```

If the value does not exist in the dictionary it will return a `None`.

Another example of value, not exits.

```
In [5]: dicto = [{100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3, 71: 4}, {100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3}, {105: 1, 100: 2, 90: 3, 80: 4}]
   ...: listo = [70,80,105]
   ...: 

In [6]: [j.get(i) for i,j in zip(listo,dicto)]
Out[6]: [None, 3, 1]
```

Comment: upvoted for `None`s. This should be the desired output, imho

Comment: @AliYılmaz, yes, this should be the desired output, but, the OP needs to clarify this. Currently, OP's code skips it if the key is missing.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar thats right. else, output does not clarify what `listo` element is missing at `dicto`.

Answer (score 1):

We can run through for loops in order to iterate through each dictionary in the list of dictionaries. Below is an example:

```
dicto = [{100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3, 70: 4}, {100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3}, {105: 1, 100: 2, 90: 3, 80: 4}]

listo = [70, 80, 105]
track = []

first_dict = dicto[0]
second_dict = dicto[1]
third_dict = dicto[2]

for key, value in first_dict.items():
     if key == listo[0]:
        track.append(value)

for key, value in second_dict.items():
     if key == listo[1]:
         track.append(value)

for key, value in third_dict.items():
     if key == listo[2]:
         track.append(value)



print(track)
```

Here is your output:

```
[4, 3, 1]
```

We create three variables that store each of the dicts, and if the dict key matches the index that we are looking for in the list that corresponds with 70, 80, or 105 [the 0, 1, or 2 index], then we append it to the track list.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
track = []
for index, element in enumerate(listo):
    if element in dicto[index]:
        track.append(dicto[index][element])
print(track)
```

prints:

```
[4, 3, 1]
```